# Retrofit 2.0 with jackson convertor

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to import retrofit with its jackson convertor, but gives me error

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson
```

**app.gradle**

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
```

Comment: obviously you forgot about version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add the version:

`compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.1.0'`